# Modelling changes to a relation in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a one-to-many relation in SQL. That's simple:

```
CREATE TABLE relation (oneId INTEGER, manyId INTEGER);
```

This relation can change at any time. However, I need to store these changes separately --- I need to know what's changed, and potentially roll them back.

I'm at a loss as to how to model this cleanly in SQL. The best I've come up with so far is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE changes (oneId INTEGER, oldManyId INTEGER, newManyId INTEGER);
CREATE VIEW fused (oneId, manyId) AS [...complex SQL here...]
```

So: changes get written to `changes`; we indicate that any specific relation `(oneId, oldManyId)` is superseded by `(oneId, newManyId)`, we set `manyId` to `NULL` to indicate that we're removing an entry; and then we use a view to fuse the two tables together to provide a unified view of the state of the world.

But the fused view is pretty hard. As far as I can tell I need a join over both tables and then per-row computation to decide what the value of `manyId` should be. I'm concerned about performance; I need to do fast lookups of all the `many`s associated with each `one`. I've ended up with:

```
SELECT relation.oneId, COALESCE(changes.newManyId, relation.manyId)
FROM relation LEFT JOIN changes
ON relation.oneId = changes.oneId
  AND relation.manyId IN (changes.oldManyId, changes.newManyId)
  AND changes.newManyId IS NOT NULL -- eliminate removed tuples
UNION ALL
SELECT oneId, newManyId FROM changes WHERE oldManyId IS NULL -- include added tuples
```

This query scares me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just add an auto-incrementing id or effective date and use that to determine which relationship is correct at any given time.  Even better --  use both an effective and end date.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I think there'd still be a lot of housekeeping --- I'd need to provide a view which takes the raw relation data and extracts only the most recent version; I think that deleting rows would be hard here. I'd also need to search the relation for duplicate entries to find the relations which had changed. I think it's conceptually simpler, but I couldn't say whether it'd be more efficient.

Comment: Temporal tables might help; support depends on the RDBMS, e.g. sql server 2016 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables)